# How do I set parts of a file into different variables in Python?

Tags: python, variables

For example, I have a text file that looks like this:

```
Last, First; 83; 73
Random, Name; 80; 90
```

What I want to know is how do I set variables so it looks like this:

```
names = ['Last, First', 'Random, Name']
num1 = [83, 73]
num2 = [80, 80]
```

Edit:

```
filename = input('Enter the name of the file: ')
f = open(filename)
for data in f:
    for info in data.split(';'):
        print(info)
```

So, I did that to see if the split would work. It separated them into new lines like this:

```
Last, First
83
73
Random, Name
80
90
```

I also tried using zip() but it didn't work.

```
for name, num1, num2 in zip(data)
```

Comment: What have you tried? It'll help us help you if we know what you did that went wrong. Otherwise, we're pretty much just writing you code.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the data is consistent, you can use the `csv` module and transpose the data... eg:

```
import csv

with open('input') as fin:
    scin = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=';', skipinitialspace=True)
    data = zip(*scin)
    header = data[0]
    nums = zip(*data[1:])

print header
# ('Last, First', 'Random, Name')
print vals
# [('83', '73'), ('80', '90')]
```

Note here that `nums[0]` is the equivalent of your `num1`, and `nums[1]` the equivalent of your `num2` etc... as you almost certainly do not need/want separate variables. You may wish to consider converting to an appropriate datatype if a string isn't suitable.